# Posting file to Flask with cURL returns 400 error

Tags: python, curl, flask

I want to post a file using cURL to a Flask view. However, I get a 400 error in response.  Why does the command below fail?

```
@app.route('/deploy/partial', methods=['POST'])
def postfile():
    try:
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join('/home/test/test.txt', filename))
        return 'OK', 200
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@FILEPATH" http://127.0.0.1:25252/deploy/partial

Unexpected error: <class 'werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls'>
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2016 22:57:43] "POST /deploy/partial HTTP/1.1" 400 

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.11 Python/3.4.3
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 19:31:07 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not    understand.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the

Unexpected error: .newcls'>

after I accidentally renamed request.form['name'] to request.form['ame']
(note the wrong 'ame') while my form field is
name = StringField(...)

I changed request.form['ame'] to request.form['name'] and the error disappeared, i.e. flask works

Not sure if this is your case too.

Comment: hey, at first i thought the same but it appears to be random in my case... e.g. i post 10 identical file with identical curl arguments. . the first 4 or 5 works finr and the other throw thr exception...